# Differential equation representing the LTI system in this block diagram

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, signal-processing

> Find the differential equation that represents this following LTI system [image: block diagram]

---

I found

$$y(t) = \int \left( x(t) - 6 \int y(t) - 5 y(t)\right)$$

But after finding this differential equation of system, I need to find $y(t)$ for input $$x(t) = (e^{−t} + e^{−4t} )u(t)$$ by assuming system is at rest initially for this input. Should I also assume this initial rest situation for question part a.

Comment: Please edit the rest.

Answer (score 1):

You can now take the derivatives of this equation to get a differential equation, resulting in
$$
y''+5y'+6y=x'.
$$
You can avoid dealing with the derivative of $x$ by setting $v=y'-x$ so that
\begin{align}
y'&=x+v,\\
v'&=-5(v+x)-6y.
\end{align}
Or use the Laplace transform formalism to get to the solution.